# How do I get an object when I click on the holder? kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a RecycleView in which I display orders (This is my class).

To get an order basket, I need to know the order ID.

I tried to take the ID from RecycleView, but the ID and position may not match.
I would be grateful for a piece of code that solves my problem correctly.

**My code:**

```
class HomeItemAdapter(private val viewModel: MainViewModel)
    : ListAdapter<Order, HomeItemAdapter.ViewHolder>(HomeItemDiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_main, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(position)
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        private val title: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_title)

        fun bind(pos: Int) {
            title.text = viewModel.orderList.value?.get(pos)?.publicOrderId ?: "Error: No Public ID"

            view.setOnClickListener {
                /*view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_detail,
                        setupInputData(item, adapterPosition).arguments)*/
                //view.getTag(pos).
                view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_orderFragment,setupInputData2(adapterPosition).arguments)
            }
        }
    }
    private fun setupInputData2(adapterPosition: Int): NavDirections{
        return HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToOrderFragment(adapterPosition)
    }

    class HomeItemDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Order>() {

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Order, newItem: Order): Boolean = oldItem == newItem

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Order, newItem: Order): Boolean = oldItem == newItem
    }
 }
```

**HomeFragment**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    private lateinit var recycler: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_main, container, false)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        activity?.let {
           // viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(it).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
            viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
            setRecyclerItemsObserver()
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // set fab listener to start an action
        view.addNewButton.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_create, null))

        recycler = view.recycler
        setupRecycler()
    }

    private fun setRecyclerItemsObserver() {
        viewModel.getItems().observe(this, Observer { list ->
            list?.let {
                (recycler.adapter as? HomeItemAdapter)?.submitList(it)
            }
        })
    }

    private fun setupRecycler() {
        recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        val itemDecor = DividerItemDecoration(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL)
        recycler.addItemDecoration(itemDecor)
        recycler.adapter = HomeItemAdapter(viewModel)
        viewModel.prepareItems()
    }
}
```

**MainViewmodel Class**

```
   class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val orderList: MutableLiveData<List<Order>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun getItems(): LiveData<List<Order>> = orderList

    fun prepareItems() {
        apiClient.getApiService().getOrders().enqueue(object : Callback<ResultOrders> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResultOrders>?, response: Response<ResultOrders>?) {
                if (response?.body() != null) {
                    orderList.postValue(response.body()!!.results.toMutableList())
                } else
                    Log.d("[INFO]", "Body is null")
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResultOrders>?, t: Throwable?) {
                if (t != null && call != null) {
                    Log.i(
                            "[ERROR]",
                            t.message + "\t" + t.localizedMessage + "\t" + t.printStackTrace() + "\t" + t.cause + "\n" + call.request()
                    )
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

**How can I get an order object ( in my case order.id) when clicking on the holder?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the right solution, but it will work!
You can simply add an internal variable to the

> `inner class ViewHolder`

```
inner class ViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    var id = -1
    private val title: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_title)

    fun bind(pos: Int) {
        id = viewModel.orderList.value?.get(pos)?.id!!;
        title.text = viewModel.orderList.value?.get(pos)?.publicOrderId ?: "Error: No Public ID"

        view.setOnClickListener {
            /*view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_detail,
                    setupInputData(item, adapterPosition).arguments)*/
            //view.getTag(pos).
            view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_orderFragment,setupInputData2(id).arguments)
        }
    }
}
private fun setupInputData2(idOrder: Int): NavDirections{
    return HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToOrderFragment(idOrder)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass this information from onBindViewHolder because that has the current index of the row. Expose an interface from your fragment into your recycler view which can call some method passing the order id as a parameter.

Something like this

```
interface Callback {
   void passOrderId(String orderId);
}

Fragment implement Callback {
    @Override
     void passOrderId(String orderId) {
        // use the order id here
     }

     // pass this interface to RecyclerView while creating its object
     RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new Adapter(this);

}
```

Adapter.java

```
public void onBindViewHodler(.... int index) {
      callback.passOrderId(orderList.get(index).getid());
}
```

Comment: The problem is that here the index will be equal to the line number, and not order.id isn't it?

Comment: You must be showing orders in each row right ? Is it not something that needs to be shown in Recycler view, then your Adapter should not know about this. You should look into other way to handle this order id field.

Comment: If you are showing orders in the list and order id must be the part of the order model class only